# $\sum_{1\leq a,b\leq n}\mathcal{P}(\gcd(a,b,n))$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

I want to simplify the following expression

$$\sum_{1\leq a,b\leq n}\mathcal{P}(\gcd(a,b,n)),$$ where $\mathcal{P}(x)$ is the number of partitions of $x$.

It turned out this number is the top betti number of the $C_n\times C_n$ covering of the Hilbert scheme of $n$ points of the 2-torus. Simplifying this expression may lead to other possible ways of calculating it.

When $n$ is prime, the expression becomes $\mathcal{P}(n)+n^2-1$. The first few terms are 1
5
11
23
31
60
63
109
126
183
176
330
269
420
496
645
585
995
850. I didn't manage to find anything on OEIS.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try representing it as a product, like for the generating function of $P(n)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Introducing $d:=\gcd(a,b,n)$, we get
$$\sum_{1\leq a,b\leq n} \mathcal{P}(\gcd(a,b,n)) = \sum_{d\mid n} \mathcal{P}(d) J_2(\tfrac{n}d),$$
where $J_2(\cdot)$ is the [Jordan totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_totient_function) (see also [OEIS A007434](https://oeis.org/A007434)).

In particular, when $n$ is prime, we have the sum of just two terms:
$$\mathcal{P}(1) J_2(n) + \mathcal{P}(n) J_2(1) = n^2 - 1 + \mathcal{P}(n)$$
as expected.

Comment: I like the expression in terms of Dirichlet generating functions: $P(s)\zeta(s-2)/\zeta(s)$.